# No Pi user desktop after SCROT install, StartX

Tags: raspbian, login

I attempted to install the SCROT screenshot tool. I type startx as the instructions suggest. After this, I cannot log into the Pi desktop anymore. Upon entering the password, the screen goes black, the comes right back to the login screen. I have a monitor and keyboard attached to the Pi directly.

The password is correct as I can successfully login with Pi username using Putty.

I can see my screen saver in the background behind the login box.

Comment: Your welcome I suggest you read the rest of the forum thread I linked to in my answer. I am also going to delete most of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know what caused the problem, you can fix it by doing the following from the command prompt:

```
cd
```

This will change to your home directory (assuming the default Raspbian install - this will be **/home/pi**)

next rename the **.Xauthority** file:

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.backup
```

reboot your Pi

```
sudo reboot
```

then startx as normal:

```
startx
```

If x starts successfully you can remove the **.Xauthority.backup** file:

```
rm ~/.Xauthority.backup
```

This Raspberry Pi Foundation [forum thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5572) contains some further details.